# C++ SSL SMTP Server Protocol after StartSSL confusion

Tags: c++, openssl, smtp, smtp-auth

I need to write a custom SMTP service in C++, there is a requirement that it needs to support SSL, I have been looking at the two SMTP [RFC 2821](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt) and [RFC  5321](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5321/), but I can't figure out message ordering.  I am getting the following from a mail client.

Messages received from mail client:

```
[Received from client] EHLO PAULMORRISSAB5A
[Received from client] STARTTLS
[Received from client] ▬▬☺
```

What is the last message and what should the server reply with please?

Comment: It looks like the tail end of Base64 padding (UUencoding?), and then one garbage character.

Comment: @jww, So the ::recv() has been corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

SSL connection to smtp server with STARTTLS (without authentication):

```
S: <waits for connection on TCP port 25>
C: <opens connection>
S: 220 mail.imc.org SMTP service ready
C: EHLO mail.example.com\r\n
S: 250-mail.imc.org offers a warm hug of welcome
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-STARTTLS
S: 250 DSN
C: STARTTLS\r\n
S: 220 Go ahead
```

> ## Openssl part in c++ for example (you dont need send this 3 lines)
>
> ```
>     C: <starts TLS negotiation>
>     C & S: <negotiate a TLS session>
>     C & S: <check result of negotiation>
> ```

```
C: EHLO mail.example.com\r\n
S: 250-mail.imc.org touches your hand gently for a moment
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250 DSN
C: mail from: <email>\r\n
S: 250 OK
C: rcpt to: <email@com.com>\r\n
S: 250 OK
C: DATA\r\n
S: 354 Go adead
C: From: <email>\r\n
C: To: <email@email.to>\r\n
C: Subject: Hello costam\r\n
C:
C: Hello from email smtp
C: 
C: .
S: 250 qued as 5s4f564ds65f4
C: quit
S: 221 Bye...
```

Simple c++ ssl smtp client here: 
https://github.com/breakermind/SslSMTPClient

Comment: link for the client is 404